# Probability of death by the deadly virus

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Having the following data:

```
chance of death by virus in age 70-80: 15%
   - which is 80% of all deaths by virus
average death rate: 2%
   - female: 1%
   - male: 3%
death chance when having heart disease: 5%
```

(Let's say there's uniform distribution of gender and diseases)

What's the correct way to calculate death probability of 80 years old infected male with heart disease? Is given data enough?

Comment: No, it is not enough.  For extreme example, suppose the virus very specifically targets elderly men and young women, however it doesn't affect elderly women or young men.  We would need to know whether or not age and gender affect the chances of death by the virus independently or not.  Similarly for the interaction with heart disease.

Comment: This is why I think it might make sense to make an assumption that all the things you mentioned are independent and distributed uniformly, so the virus attacks everyone equally, and the heart diseases among death 70-80 y/o people is 80% of 5% (mainly because lack of data). This is the only way I can imagine to get any reasonable result, even though I'm aware it won't be 100% accurate

Comment: Assuming that things are independent simply because you don't have the data to calculate their dependence is not a good strategy. I respect that you want to be able to calculate this, but I'd counsel you to consider the possibility that you just can't.